# How to reset the GitHub.com password, when email is not verfied?

Tags: github

When I logged into Github.com, it says:

```
Your password is weak and can be easily guessed. You must update your password to continue using GitHub.com.
```

And the page leads to resetting the password. When my email address is input, it says:

```
That address is not a verified primary email or is not associated with a personal user account. Organization billing emails are only for notifications
```

I have the username and correct password, but not the email. I'm wondering how to get the `verified primary email`, or can I reset the password in other ways?

Comment: Have you got it sorted?

Answer (score 1):

You can now generate tokens for unlimited time using your old password which you can store in your local machine to access your repositories from the command line.

Comment: ok How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

That address is either invalid, not a verified primary email or is not associated with a personal user account. Organization billing emails are only for notifications

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).